# A question regarding the consistency of Nelson's Predicative Arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy, foundations

Following Dan Willard (from his paper "Self-Verifying Axiom Systems, the Incompleteness Theorem, and Related Reflection Systems", found on his [homepage](http://www.cs.albany.edu/FacultyStaff/profiles/willard.htm), pdf [here](http://www.cs.albany.edu/%7Edew/m/jsl1.pdf)):

> "Define an axiom system $\alpha$ to be *self-verifying* iff
>
> i) $\alpha$ can formally verify its own consistency (by some reasonable definition of self-consistency), and
>
> ii) the axiom system $\alpha$ is in fact consistent."

Question:  Is Nelson's system of Predicative Arithmetic self-verifying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Nelson's system extends Robinson arithmetic, so it's subject to Gödel's incompleteness theorems.  Willard's systems can't prove the totality of addition or multiplication (see the wiki article) and that lets them avoid being able to carry out the diagonalization needed to create unprovable sentences.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-verifying_theories

Comment: Can it be shown that Nelson's Predicative Arithmetic can prove the totality of addition and multiplication?  Can it be shown that it can prove the totality of the successor operation?

Comment: (cont.)  See Nelson's book _Predicative Arithmetic_, chapters 29-31.  These chapters (possibly) suggest otherwise.  Contrariwise, can anyone (now, themselves,  or from the literature) derive the First and Second Incompleteness Theorems in Nelsons system?

Comment: Furthermore, let me quote from page 5 of "Self-Verifying Axiom Systems, the Incompleteness Theorem,  and Related Reflection Principles" :  "Nelson [in _Predicative Arithmetic_---my comment] proved that Robinson's System $\mathrm Q$ (with linear ordering) could prove a version of [$\forall$y {Tang(y)  $\supset$ $\lnot$$Prf_{\alpha}$('0=1' ,y)}, where  $Prf_{\alpha}$('0=1',y) denotes a formula indicating that y is a Goedel number of a proof from axiom system $\alpha$ ($\alpha$=$\mathrm Q$ in Nelson's case) of the sentence (0=1 in this case) with the Goedel number '0=1' --my comment] about

Comment: (cont.) itself when Tang(y) was taken to be a delicately specified "Definable Cut" of the Natural Numbers and "$Prf$" denoted Herbrand Deduction."  The question is, is this sufficient to say that Predicative Arithmetic is self-justifying?

Comment: Whether Herbrand consistency on a definable cut is a reasonable notion of self-justification is totally a matter of opinion, however, note that under this definition, plenty of common theories are self-justifing: e.g., $I\Sigma_1$, $\mathrm{ACA}_0$, or $\mathrm{NBG}$; in fact, every consistent finitely axiomatizable sequential theory is.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  Can you derive Goedel's First and Second Incompleteness Theorems for Nelson's Predicative Arithmetic?  If so, I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: (cont.) (See _Predicative Arithmetic_, Chapter 31, pp. 175-6, in particular pg. 176, where Nelson claims that Predicative Arithmetic is self-consistent.)

Comment: What *is* “Nelson’s Predicative Arithmetic”? I’m not really familiar with the book, but as far as I can see from a quick glance, Nelson did not introduce any fixed theory under that name, but a bunch of related theories, denoted $Q$ with various indices and decorations. Since all of them are recursively axiomatized extensions of Robinson’s $Q$, they are all subject to Gödel’s First and Second Incompleteness Theorems (as none already wrote in their answer).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  I was looking through Nelson's book, and I believe that many of his versions of $\mathrm Q$ are just extensions by definitions of $\mathrm Q$.  This is not, I think, the issue at hand here.  The issue at hand, I think, is his  predicative _interpretation_ of $\mathrm Q$.  Consider  the following quote from Chapter 18 (pp. 80-1) of his book:  "The [Hilbert-Ackermann--my comment] Consistency Theorem can be used to prove the consistency of $\mathrm Q$, so if  we could establish, within our theory, both it and Goedel's theorem on the  impossibility of self-consistency proofs, then

Comment: (cont.) we would have a contradiction.  This indicates that at least one of these two pillars of finitary mathematical logic, the Hilbert-Ackermann Consistency Theorem and Goedel's Second [Incompleteness--my comment] Theorem, makes an appeal to impredicative concepts."  What is one to make of statements like that?